# How to push my calculated new product price through addToCartUrls.push function in Magento?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, magento

I was implementing code from url

http://www.lindenlan.net/2009/09/27/how-to-simultaneously-add-multiple-products-to-a-magento-shopping-cart/

for Simultaneously Add Multiple Products To A Magento Shopping Cart and it works perfectly (`addToCartUrls.push($('url_' + id).value + 'qty/' + qty);`) but I want to push my new calculated price of product to shopping cart how could I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code to add multiple products to cart programatically, check if it helps :

```
<?php 
$productCollection = // array collection of products you want to add to cart;
foreach($productCollection as $product){

    $loadProductData = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
    $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
    $OrderquoteItem = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item');
    $quoteItem = $OrderquoteItem->setProduct($loadProductData);
    //custom options to show user on cart page
    $a_options = array(
        'options' => array(
           'label' => 'Added :',
           'value' => "Programatically",
        ));
        //add above options array to this cart item which is going to get added on cart
    $quoteItem->addOption(array(
          'code' => 'additional_options',
          'value' => serialize($a_options),
      ));
     // set price and quantity
    $quoteItem->setQuote($quote)
        ->setQty($qty)
        ->setOriginalCustomPrice(0.00)//pass your custom price here
        ->save();
}
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);

?>
```

Comment: Thanx for Answer
I am using "addToCartUrls.push($('url_' + id).value + 'qty/' + qty);" to add products into shopping cart let me know the solution of adding my custom price of product through above function!

Comment: Try to pass "price" parameter in these URLS. But i am not quite sure it will work. Most of the magento bulk add-to-cart functions take only quantity as a parameter. I will still check if passing custom price is feasible in the function you are using.

Comment: I have tried to add 1 more parameter of price but it doesn't work and not functioning too! That because I'm stuck there!

Let me know the easiest way to add multiple products to cart if you have!

Comment: The code I have written above is the very much suitable to add custom prices for single as well as multiple products. It will also help you to show the customer a cart-item comment if you have set any offered custom price to it

Comment: Can you please post code of list.phtml so I'll clear my idea
Actually I am new in Magento sorry to trouble but please thanks in advance

Comment: What I will suggest is, 
1)override Checkout/CartController.php's AddAction. Lets say your product is ABC, send the SKUs or IDs of procuct you want to add with the product ABC. 
2) AddAction will by Default add the product ABC to cart, what you need to do it fetch those extra product Ids/SKUs and load  them into array. 
3) Use the code I have posted above to add remaining products with your custom prices. 
What I think is you are looking for a concept like Freebie or accessories where when you buy a mobile for example, you add its cover to cart with custom price as Rs.0.

Comment: Hey please let me know your email address so I will let you know aal the details properly!

Comment: Mail me the details at blastfreak@gmail.com

Comment: I have mailed you the details please check and reply!

Comment: Check your email, I replied on it :)

Comment: Mailed you the details of Mine Teamviewer

Comment: Hi Blastfreak I am waiting for your reply!